# Allow specific number of NSWindow copies to be visible

Tags: cocoa, count, nswindow

I have a button in my application, when you click it it opens a new NSWindow.  However, if you keep on clicking it it will open another NSWindow.  How can I limit the number of visible windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the button.  If you have a button that creates a new window, then it should create a new window.  If you don't want the user to create a new window, don't let them click the button.

**edit** if you're dealing with something like a preferences window, then you should probably be using an `NSWindowController` subclass to control the window.  Clicking the button should essentially do (`preferencesWindowController` is an ivar):

```
- (void) showPreferences:(id)sender {
  if (preferencesWindowController == nil) {
    preferencesWindowController = [[PreferencesWindowController alloc] init];
  }
  [preferencesWindowController showWindow:sender];
}
```

Comment: It's more like a preferences window.